# Autofill a table with a dynamic range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, autofill, vba

I'm trying to autofill a table with a variable range based on date (e.g. Date range of 6/10/2018 - 6/13/2018 it autofills from the last row which is 6/10/2018 to 6/13/2018).

Here is my code so far where at the auto fill step it kicks a mis-match error:

```
Set Table = Adspend.Worksheets("Summary").ListObjects("Spend")
Set TableCell = Table.Range.Cells(2, Table.ListColumns(1).Index)

LastRow = Table.Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

If IsEmpty(Table.Range.Cells(2, Table.ListColumns(1).Index)) = True Then
Table.Range.Cells(2, Table.ListColumns(1).Index) = 
Adspend.Worksheets("Summary").Range("B1").Value
End If


If TableCell.Value < Adspend.Worksheets("Summary").Range("C1").Value Then
        DatePeriod = Adspend.Worksheets("Summary").Range("C1").Value - 
TableCell.Value

        NewDate = LastRow + DatePeriod



        Table.Range.Cells(2, Table.ListColumns(1).Index).AutoFill Destination:=Table.Range(Cells(LastRow, Table.ListColumns(1)), Cells(NewDate, Table.ListColumns(1)))




End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first column of your Spend table is in column O and there is nothing beneath it, switch the autofill to a data series using the last date value in column O and an integer in C1 as the stop.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim datePeriod As Long

    With Worksheets("Summary")
        datePeriod = .Range("C1").Value

        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, .ListObjects("Spend").Range.Column).End(xlUp)
            .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlChronological, _
                        Date:=xlDay, Step:=1, Stop:=.Value + datePeriod
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to convert that to ListObject syntax, it shouldn't be hard but a DataSeries  with a stop should be easier than an autofill into a destination range.

Comment: Hey you actually found an error in my sheet.  The problem I have is that the start of the table is unknown and not located in O.  I'm going to update my code above to reflect that the lastrow shouldn't look in O, but instead the first column of the table.

Comment: Edited to reflect unknown first column.

Comment: Hey Thank you for the solution, but it filled the date from the start date until the end of time.  I need it to fill from the date in the LastRow to the end date in C1

Comment: I thought datePeriod was an integer representing the number of days. If it is the actual stop date then change `Stop:=.Value + datePeriod` to `Stop:=datePeriod`.